# PHP MySQL, sum of rows based on datetime row

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, sum

I'm trying to sum number of persons based on datetime rows.

this is how my table looks like:

```
id | date              | person |
---+-------------------+--------+
1  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  3     |
---+-------------------+--------+    
2  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  2     |
---+-------------------+--------+ 
3  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|  3     |
---+-------------------+--------+ 
4  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|  3     |
---+-------------------+--------+
```

What i want my query to do is: Sum all persons based on date. But i think my problem is not query it self (or maybe it is), but the datetime. I have something like

```
$date = "26.12.2013";
$date = strtotime(date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date)));
$date = date("Y-m-d", $date); 
$query= "SELECT '$date', SUM('person') totalperson FROM table_name WHERE date='$date' GROUP BY '$date'";
```

but the number returned is 2016 and expected is 8 :)

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: cannot test if it will help but don't `group by` on the column value but the column name `group by date` the column name date can cause problems if you don't use ` around it

Comment: GROUPing BY a static value does not make any sense – you want to group by the column, not by a specific value. (If you want to restrict the result set to only a certain date by value – that’s what the WHERE clause is for.)

Comment: I know, i actualy had correct query few hours ago, but i was echoing wrong query result. Because query result is array, where [0] is date and [1] is the actual person number :P i should have figured that out first time when result was 2016 because 2013 (year) + 3 is 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What db engine do you use?

Anyway, this should work:

```
$date = "2013-12-26 00:00:00";
$query = "
  SELECT date, SUM(person) totalperson 
  FROM table_name WHERE date='$date' 
  GROUP BY date
";
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped =) plus i echoed wrong query result. result is date and total amount of persons.

Answer (score 4):

```
SUM(`person`)
```

Use backticks for column name,you are suming a string

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    date, 
    SUM(person) totalperson 
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATE(date) = '$date' 
GROUP BY date
```

Use DATE() function

you are providing date string in date time column